# Find dates of particular month between date ranges

Tags: php

I have two date ranges (startdate1, enddate1) and (startdate2, enddate2). I want to find dates of particular month like 12(12 for December) between above 4 dates in PHP? Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  What you're asking is not entirely clear.

Comment: i have two date range ("01-01-2010","30-03-2010") and ("10-02-2010","20-02-2010") .

Comment: i want 02(february) month  dates between above 4 date.

Comment: than result will be ("10-02-2010") to ("20-02-2010") means 11 days of february will be common

Answer (score 0):

This [page here](http://edrackham.com/php/get-days-between-two-dates-using-php/) explains how to get the days between two dates.

I hope this was helpful.